# Move Rectangle Inside Rectangle when rotating Outer Rectangle

Tags: c#, javascript

Black Region no need to rotate, But I want to find the postion for the Markup after 
Image roates.

Image Roatation is happends through the Internal API I only want to place the markup which lies in the Image Region in the Diagram shown above. Please share ur idea how do I achieve the same automation in the code.

Outer Rectangle (here is Image ) Width and Height is known (width, height)
Also inital postion for the Markup (Black region) left, top, right, bottom also known. Is there any way to automate the same with Code in any language or mathematical equations.

Pleas check the attached image....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes but depends on how you want the markup positioned.

Assumption 1.

All margins are measured from the edges of the image.

In the initial position the width of the image is W and its height is H.
The left margin of the markup is L and the top margin T. The width of the markup is w and the height is h.

Assumption 2

Margins are based on absolute values.

At 90deg the right margin of the markup is L and the top margin is T. Then the left margin of the markup is H-(w+L).

At 180deg the right margin is L and the bottom margin is T. Then the left margin of the markup is W-(w+L) and the top margin of the markup is H-(h+T)

At 270deg the left margin is L and the top margin is W-(h+T)

Assumption 3

Margins are relative to the proportions of the image.

In the initial position the left margin relative to image width is L/W, the top margin relative to height is T/H

At 90deg the right margin is R where R/H = L/W and R=LH/W and the left margin is H-(w+R)
the top margin is S where S/W = T/H and S=TW/H

At 180deg the right margin is L and the bottom margin is T. Then the left margin is W-(w+L) and the top margin is H-(h+T)

At 270deg the left margin is R where R/H = L/W and R=LH/W and the bottom margin is S where S/W = T/H and S=TW/H and the top margin is W-(h+S)

Hope this helps